# MySQL index being ignored for subquery range

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright, here's a simple enough question about indices and subqueries. I'm using MariaDB 5.5.36 + MyISAM, here's my table structure for `leaderboard`. It contains about 50 million rows across ~2000 levels.

```
int userid,
int levelid,
int score,

index (userid, levelid),
index (levelid, score)
```

This query, meant to return the rank of each score in a level for a given user, runs very slow...

```
SELECT levelid, (
    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
    FROM leaderboard
    WHERE score > l.score AND levelid = l.levelid
) AS rank
FROM leaderboard AS l
WHERE userid = 12345;
```

I've tried using a self-join group approach as well, which runs in half the time as above but still unacceptably slow:

```
SELECT x.levelid, COUNT(y.score) AS rank
FROM leaderboard AS x
LEFT JOIN leaderboard AS y ON x.levelid = y.levelid AND y.score > x.score
WHERE x.userid = {0}
GROUP BY x.levelid;
```

... while this alternative runs about 100x faster (pseudocode, looping over the results in an application outside the DB or in a stored procedure or something and running the subquery separately 2000 times with a constant):

```
results = execute(""SELECT levelid, score
    FROM leaderboard
    WHERE userid = 12345"");

for each row in results:
    execute(""SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
        FROM leaderboard
        WHERE score > %d AND levelid = %d
    "".printf(row.score, row.levelid));
```

EXPLAIN tells me that the subquery in the slow example has a key_len of 4 bytes (just levelid) while the fast version uses 8 (levelid, score). Interesting side note, if "score > l.score" is replaced with "score = l.score" it switches to using all 8, but obviously that doesn't give me the answer I'm looking for.

Is there something I'm not understanding about how the index fundamentally works? Is there a better way to write this ranking query? Would it be more efficient to add a `rank` column to my table and update it every time a highscore is achieved (that could mean updating up to 400k rows for one single score achievement)?

Comment: Depending on the data distribution pattern, a clustered index could be more optimal for such queries. Considering MySQL's way of picking clustered index, could you try changing the index `index (levelid, score)` to `index (levelid, score, userid)`, mark this as unique and compare performance?